# Refs with instance variable gives error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a React component that I'm migrating to `tsx` file and I'm getting an error `Property 'name' does not exist on type 'NameComponent'`.

Here is my component:

```
class NameComponent extends React.Component<NameComponentProps> {
    render() {
        return (
            <Modal>
                <Modal.Header>
                    Enter Name
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <ControlLabel>Name: </ControlLabel>
                        <FormControl type="text"
                            placeholder='Enter name'
                            inputRef={(ref) => this.name = ref}
                            onChange={() => this.props.onValidate({ name: this.name.value })}
                        />
                        <FormControl.Feedback />
                    </FormGroup>
               </Modal.Body>
            </Modal>
        );
    }
}
```

There is a red undeline on the occurences of `this.name`.  This worked back when I had this file in `.js` format.

How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a private class field on your component that will store the `name` HTMLInputElement.

```
class NameComponent extends React.Component<NameComponentProps> {
    private name: HTMLInputElement;

    render() {
        return (
            <Modal>
                <Modal.Header>
                    Enter Name
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <ControlLabel>Name: </ControlLabel>
                        <FormControl type="text"
                            placeholder='Enter name'
                            inputRef={(ref) => this.name = ref}
                            onChange={() => this.props.onValidate({ name: this.name.value })}
                        />
                        <FormControl.Feedback />
                    </FormGroup>
               </Modal.Body>
            </Modal>
        );
    }
}
```